# How to update the password and 'is_staff' status while using django.contrib.auth models

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-templates

I am developing a web based application in which i need to update the password and is_staff status of a user from Admin(template) page. To do this i created a template which are showing the list of all registered users. see the template:

```
   {% for obj in users_list.object_list %}
        <tr class="{% cycle 'odd' 'even' %}">
            <td>{{obj}}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url user_detail user.pk%}">{{obj.first_name}}</a></td>
            <td>{{obj.last_name}}</td>
            <td>{{obj.email}}</td>
            <td>{{obj.is_staff}}</td>
```

The above code showing the list of all users includes their Full name, Email and is_staff status. What i want, when admin will click on the user name (i uses the href attributes). It will get the option to update the password and is_staff status for a clicked user at open page.

To do this i am not able to find out how to pass the id of user in following line. I tried with **user.pk** but it always given 1 to me. May be it is returning the current loginned user id but the loginned user is super user also:

```
 <td><a href="{% url user_detail user.pk%}">{{obj.first_name}}</a></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference to the user is `obj`, not `user`. So `obj.pk` should work.

Comment: @ Daniel Thanks, To Point out my mistake.I was reading following official doc  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/ and get to knew about updating the password. Is their any possibility to update the pass without using Django-Form. I mean, Admin write the password on text field at template and from template it will update directoly to the database without even uses of views.py ?